# Update a specific rows and columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table1

```
column1 | column2 | column 3
-----------------------------
A       | 100     | a
B       | 200     | b
C       | 300     | c
```

Table2

```
column1 | column3
-----------------
A       | aaa
C       | ccc
```

How do I replace `column3` from `Table2` in `Table1`?

```
SELECT column1,
       column3
FROM Table1
WHERE column1 IN ('A', 'C')
```

Output:

```
column1 | column2 | column 3
----------------------------
A       | 100     | aaa
B       | 200     | b
C       | 300     | ccc
```

Comment: Are you really looking for an `UPDATE` or just `SELECT`ing the data?

Comment: @Sami yes sorry... update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using an update with inner join

```
update  Table1 
set Table1.column3 = Table2.column3
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.column1 = table2.column1
```

or if you need only updated  A and C

```
update  Table1 
set Table1.column3 = Table2.column3
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.column1 = table2.column1  
  AND Table1.Column1 IN ('A','C')
```

Comment: Where is required for specific rows to be updated only.